# Celery: Single instance of an active task in a distributed environment

Tags: celery, distributed-computing

I have a requirement where my application submits a certain kind of task. This task is submitted by the clients. To make sure that they don't end up submitting too many tasks, every time they submit a task, I check the processes that are running and if they were submitted by the same client. If so the task will not be submitted.
I want to scale horizontally for these kind of tasks. So I'll have multiple workers running on different machines, to ensure higher availability, but then I want to make sure that only one instance of the task is actively being processed and that task should complete before another one submitted by the same client is processed.

For example, if the chronology of tasks being submitted is-

```
Client 1 submits t1 
Client 1 submits t2 
Client 2 submits t3
```

If `t1` is still being processed and if a worker gets freed up, then it should pick up `t3` and not `t2`.

How can I solve this problem?
Rate limiting is not an option as I can't tell how long these tasks take.

Thanks,

Comment: I had suggested using `memcache` as a task-lock, but apparently this isn't robust enough. It appears that there may be a requirement for a fault-tolerant [Distributed Lock Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager).

Comment: @MattH - I'm trying to analyse the worst case scenario that may occur if I go with the memcached approach that you had suggested and if the key for the lock gets evicted. I've been also reading about apache zookeeper and similar tools that have been suggested in forums. I don't want to make it any more complex than it needs to be. Will post my findings and/or solutions here later. If a DB approach works well, I might as well go with that.

Comment: I think you'll have better luck getting other suggested answers without mine here. Also recommend that you update your question with details about your processing requirements.